# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails" | In Gemfile: rails (~> 6.1.0) x64-mingw3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, spree

I'm developing a new **Ruby on Rails** project with **Spree Commerce** and while running `bundle install` I'm getting the following error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
rails (~> 6.1.0) x64-mingw32

spree (~> 4.1) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 4.2.0.beta, which depends on
  spree_core (= 4.2.0.beta) was resolved to 4.2.0.beta, which depends on
    rails (~> 6.0.0)
```

I'm following [Spree Commerce Docs](https://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/tutorials/getting_started_tutorial.html) for its installation.

I'm on **Windows 10**, using **Ruby 2.7.2**, **Bundler 2.2.3** and **Rails 6.1.0** and with that, my Gemfile includes:

```
gem 'spree', '~> 4.1'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 4.2'
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.9'
```

I tried to remove the spree gems and then run the default Gemfile and it installs the dependencies successfully but throws the above error when I add those gems.

**I have tried all the following methods but Nothing worked:**

- Deleted Gemfile.lock
- `bundle update`
- `bundle install --full-index`
- Checked environment variables
- Reinstalled rails project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spree [doesn't support Ruby on Rails 6.1 yet](https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/10576). That is planned for Spree 4.3.

Therefore the only option for you is to downgrade Ruby on Rails to `~> 6.0.3`.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation, I just figured it out and it worked!